# Why can't I navigate to this.$refs.toLocation in Vue 3 using a variable?

Tags: vuejs3

How go to this.$refs.toLocation where toLocation is a variable with value 'interesse'?

I can go to this.$refs.interesse but not to this.$refs.toLocation.

Program is written in JavaScript / Vue 3.

I tried replacing toLocation with $toLocation but that isn't the solution. Also tried adding const toLocation = ref('Vue.js') but then I get error ref is not defined.

Comment: The fact that `interesse` is an accessible property seems pretty suspect to me. Adding random lines (like `const toLocation = ...`) won't help you, you need to update the property held in `$refs`, possibly even ensuring you're referring to the same `$refs` object (not a Vue lord).

Comment: `this.$refs` is Vue 2 Options API syntax.  `ref('value')` is Vue 3 Composition API syntax.  You can use either syntax in Vue 3 so it depends on what syntax you've chosen.  `ref is not defined` is an easy issue to solve, it means you haven't imported ref: `import { ref } from 'vue'`.  Definitely review the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#reactive-variables-with-ref) if you haven't yet.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the `ref is not defined` issue and pointing out that `this.$refs` is Vue 2 syntax. I have asked a new question with more detail as to what I need [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76331791/1837293).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that solution is adding toLocation as a key reference to $refs array like: this.$refs[toLocation] which can then be used for instance like this.$refs[toLocation].scrollIntoView()